# Uploading files on server through SFTP

Tags: file-sharing, sftp, winscp

In my region, we have proxy to connect to the internet. So, we don't have direct connection.I dont have control panel on my website. To upload my files to the server through SFTP, I was using WinsCP along with Your freedom. But since, your freedom allows only for 6 hrs a day. Its really painful to upload the files

So, can anyone suggest of installing some software on my server like (https) , so that I can upload the files through my browser. Please help in this regard.

Please comment if the question is unclear. I will try to edit it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have shell access to your server and do you have root privileges ? Otherwise I suggest running your ssh port on a non-blocked port range .

Comment: Yeah, I have root privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write a PHP script to handle uploads.

Comment: Yup... Nice idea.. Can u give some code for uploading files , where i can customize according to the folder to which I wish to upload a file

Comment: Google is your friend :) ... try searching for "upload file using php" (without quotes). Thus, you can see many examples and adopt one of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you have root :

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i eth0 --dport *PORT* -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:22
```

Where *PORT* is a port you can access normally through your proxy, what will happen is that on your server you will get rerouted to that port FROM within your server. So basically you bypass your proxy.

Most of the time I use the backup http port 8080 because it is open on most proxys. If you issue this command you can just scp/sftp to port 8080 and you will be able to upload your files.(eth0 is the NIC to which you normally connect)